# Grouping by quantiles with large data in BiqQuery

Tags: window-functions, percentile, google-bigquery

I have a large dataset of millions of rows with values x and y, and want to get the avg(y) in different quantiles of x. One way I could do that is the following code. But with a large dataset rank(), it is too intensive and I get memory usage error in BigQuery.

```
SELECT 
cast(100 * ord / num_rows as INT64) percentile,
AVG(y)
FROM
(
      SELECT
      rank() over (order by ord) ord, 
      count(*) over () num_rows ,
      y
      FROM table
)
GROUP BY 1
```

I understand that window functions are expensive for large datasets, but as I'm only interested in a bucketized percentile in a low granularity, computationally this should be possible. Is there a way to achieve this in BQ?

Comment: Well the throwaway answer might be to suggest that you just take a evenly random subset of your current very large table, and then use the same query you are already using.ell thW th

Comment: Are you performing this query frequently? Consider materializing intermediate results. Also, depending on the value of ord, you might want to use PARTITION BY to distribute the processing of data